# Using 7zip by date

Tags: command-line, backup

How can I use 7zip and the command line to select certain files by Date modified and automate by using a batch file?

Comment: I've got this exact thing running on one of my servers compressing log files. Give me a minute to look up the info and I'll get you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I used Robocopy to set aside the data that was a certain age or older, then used 7za to compress and removed the temp files. See below:

```
mkdir C:\Robocopy\Archive\Spool
mkdir C:\Robocopy\Archive\Spool\BackupLogs
mkdir C:\Robocopy\Archive\Spool\DRLogs

robocopy c:\Robocopy\Backup\BackupLogs\ C:\Robocopy\Archive\Spool\BackupLogs\ /move /minage:60
robocopy C:\Robocopy\Backup\DRLogs\ C:\Robocopy\Archive\Spool\DRLogs\ /move /minage:60
7za a c:\Robocopy\Archive\Archive.7z C:\Robocopy\Archive\Spool\

rmdir /S /Q C:\Robocopy\Archive\Spool
```

I'm dealing with two sets of log files here, one an onsite backup and one an offsite Disaster Recovery (DR) backup.

Robocopy is available in the Windows Resource Kit ([Here's the Server 2003 version](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17657)) and has some pretty cool features. The one I use here is the /minage argument, which I've used to specify that log files over 60 days old are to be moved (not copied) to appropriate folders inside a Spool directory. I then compress the contents of the Spool directory to a third location, then finally delete the Spool directory.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux systems, the following command should compress the files contained in `/path/to/your/folder` older than 7 days into the `archive.7z` file:

```
find /path/to/your/folder -mtime +7 -exec 7z a archive.7z {} \;
```

But it will not preserve the directory structure. A similar command creating a tar archive first and then compressing it using `7z` should do the job:

```
$ find /path/to/your/folder -mtime +7 -exec tar cf archive.tar {} \;
$ 7z a archive.tar.7z archive.tar
```